# Is the ratio of sum of exponentials convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{+n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

\begin{align*}
     f(x) = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\exp(c x_i)}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\exp(c x_i)},
\end{align*}

where $c, x_i \geq 0$ and $0 < a_i \leq b_i$. Is this function convex?

---

For the case of $n = 1$ this is true because $f(x)$ is just a constant. For $n>1$ it seems the Hessian might be difficult to compute. I plotted a few examples for $n = 2$ and they seem to be convex.

Comment: If you require $x_i \ge 0$ it's not $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, it's only on a subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.  Try $n=2$ with

$$ f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{e^{x_1} + 2 e^{x_2}}{2 e^{x_1} + 2 e^{x_2}}$$

Note for constant $x_1$ this starts off $< 1$ and increases to $1$ in the limit $x_2 \to +\infty$.  Such a function can't be convex.

Answer (score 1):

Set $c=1$ for simplicity (this just amounts to scaling the variables). When $n=2$, the eigenvalues of the Hessian are $0$ and
$$
\frac{2 e^{x_1+x_2} (a_2 b_1-a_1
   b_2) \left(b_1 e^{x_1}-b_2
   e^{x_2}\right)}{\left(b_1 e^{x_1}+b_2
   e^{x_2}\right)^3}.
$$
There doesn't seem to be any reason that this quantity should always be nonnegative.